# Getting SocketException (10060) when using AddAzureKeyVault during startup in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I'm getting an issue when attempting to setup an API Web App in Azure which keeps all it's secrets in KeyVault.

When trying to access it I get `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`

I've tried to run it from the cmd line with Kudu and the error is:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<SendAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()    
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
   at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)    
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String secretIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()    
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()    
   at Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in Api\Program.cs:line 15
```

This is the function:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((h, c) =>
                {
                    c.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    c.AddAzureKeyVault(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUrl", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));
                });
```

The error is triggered by the line `c.AddAzureKeyVault(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VaultUrl", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));`

I have a Vault Access Policy defined for the App, however the error doesn't appear to be authentication based, it appears to be a timeout - which is odd because they are within the same resource group/region.

Also, it does occassionally seems to work but fails most of the time.

When running from a local machine it works fine.

Comment: Are there any limitations in the networking of azure key vault? Does it allow access from selecting network or IPs?

Comment: @NancyXiong - I'm not aware of needing to setup any kind of whitelisting here - we have another API and several Azure Functions in the same Resource Group that are able to access the KeyVault without issue

Comment: `c.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/",builtConfig["AzureADApplicationId"],builtConfig["AzureADCertThumbprint"],new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());`

Comment: Is there any progress on your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. Had been using key vaults from web and console applications plus webjobs for a year but in July started hitting this randomly but frequently. Updated the NuGet version of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault to newest (3.1.7), but still this error.

```
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<FillBufferAsync>g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Rest.RetryDelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
[09/04/2020 17:34:47 > 200de2: ERR ]    at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, String secretName, String secretVersion, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve the issue for now by upgrading our App Service Plan from Basic B1 to B2.

It seems that it was working but for some reason the loading of the keyvault was so resource intensive it was failing to complete on a B1 service plan.